# Doctrine ODM Discriminator - discriminate by traits rather than types

Tags: php, mongodb, doctrine, doctrine-orm, traits

I am using Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB and storing **three different types** of documents **in a collection**. Some of them are mixins.

My question is, "Can I **discriminate** these documents **by traits** rather than types?", meaning that instead of

```
    /** @ODM\DiscriminatorField(fieldName="type") */
    ...
    ActorType1.type: singer
    ActorType2.type: musician
    ActorType3.type: singerMusician
```

I want to do something like

```
    ActorType1.canDo: sing
    ActorType2.canDo: playMusic
    ActorType3.canDo: [sing, playMusic]
```

Pseudo-code:

find(<**all** those who can **sing**>) returns all Actors of **type 1** and **type 3**.

Is this possible?

Comment: Well, you can certainly create DQL to retrieve it, automatic discriminator handling with it? Do not think it has that functionality, the discriminators are pretty basic.  So much so I do class hierarchies manually, mapped classes never work flexibly enough for my liking.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing. Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Doctrine doesn't really like inheritance.

Even using the basic Discriminator was not possible in my case.

Basically, if I am to store multiple documents in the same collection, they must not have any traits in common, including properties inherited from parent classes or imported via PHP traits.

I really hope they will make this possible in the future.